# ¿por qué "Cannot read property 'model' of undefined" en el Schema?

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Express, Mongoose

```
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.12.4"
```

- Estructura

```
./db/data/models/grupos.js
./db/data/data.js
./db/data/db-connection.js
./server.js
```

- db-connection.js

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    let db
    module.exports = function Connection() {
      if(!db) {
        db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/globalsys', 
        { useMongoClient: true })
        return db
      }
    }
```

- Server.js

```
    'use strict'
    const express = require('express')
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const app = express()
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
    // Data mongodb
    const gData = require('./db/data/data')
    // GET obtiene los datos de grupos y participantes
    app.get('/api/grupos', gData.getGrupos)
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`server listen on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
```

- El modelo grupos.js

```
  module.exports = function() {
    const db = require('../db-connection')()
    const Schema = require('mongoose').Schema
      
    const GruposSchema = Schema({
       producto: String,
       grupo: Number
    })
      
    return db.model('Grupos', GruposSchema)
 }
```

En data.js

> En esta parte hago una consulta a una bd de los grupos y las almaceno en una db de mongodb para tener un mejor manejo de los datos. Y luego exporto la función que hace la consulta en mongodb. Si no fue guardada, entonces la consulta en sql y la guarda, sino solo la consulta.

```
    'use strict'
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const sql = require('mssql')
    const config = require('./config')
    
    const mgrupos = require('../models/grupos')()
    
    function fgrupos() {
      sql.connect(config)
        .then(pool => {
          return pool.request()
            .query(`EXEC grupsParticip`)
        }).then(result => {
          if(result) {
            let resgrupos = result.recordset
    
            mgrupos.create(resgrupos, (err, grups) => {
              if(err) throw err
              console.log('grupos almacenados en mongodb...')
            })
    
            sql.close()
          } else {
            console.log('No se han encontrado grupos participantes')
            sql.close()
          }
        })
    }
    
    function getGrupos(req, res) {
      mgrupos.find({}, (err, grupos) => {
        if(err) throw err
        if(!grupos) {
          fgrupos()
          res.json({
            grupos: grupos
          })
        } else {
          res.json({
            grupos: grupos
          })
        }
      })
    }

    module.exports = { getGrupos }
```

Pero sin embargo tengo este TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined.
Que no me explico por qué??

Ayuda comunidad.

Comment: `require('../db_connection')` no `db-connection`

Comment: Gracias Gerardo. No es el problema. Lo escribí mal. El file si se llama db-connection.js tal como lo importo en el require en el modelo grupos.js.

Comment: Lo que debes hacer en `Connection()` es llamar `mongoose.connect(URL)` y despues exportar o `return` en tu caso `mongoose.connection`, nota que son diferentes.

Comment: He probado haciendo la conexión directamente en el modelo cuando hago el return de esta manera: 

return mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/globalsys', { useMongoClient: true }).model('Grupos', GruposSchema)

Hasta aquí paso el TypeError. Al parece no soporta el require del modulo db-connection.js. Tu sabes por qué?

Comment: Pero no le veo la lógica a tu código (a esa parte), no necesitas hacer `db.model` sino `mongoose.model`, osea no necesitas llamar a `Connect` por cada modelo, esa parte solo se ejecuta una vez

Comment: precisamente por que se ejecuta una sola vez lo hago en un solo modulo "db-connection.js" para llamarlo cuando se necesite y no repetir la conexión todo el tiempo.

Comment: Gracias Gerardo...

Answer (score 0):

He logrado encontrar el problema. Gracias a todos los que pasaron y leyeron mi problema de TypeError.
El problema esta en el modulo db-connection.js. Al parecer necesita tener el require('mongoose') dentro de la function a exportar, de esta manera ya pudo enviar la conexión y pasar el TypeError. Aquí el código:

file: db-connection.js

```
    'use strict'

    module.exports = function Connection() {
      const mongoose = require('mongoose')
      let db
      if(!db) {
        db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/globalsys', 
        { useMongoClient: true })

        return db
      }
    }
```

Con esto ya en el modelo grupos.js ya se puede utilizar

```
const db = require('../db-connection')()
```

y en

```
return db.model('Grupos', GruposSchema)
```

Además de tener corriendo Mongod.exe por su puesto (lo digo porque no lo plantee en el problema)

Saludos 
JL